# How to execute raster2pgsql with R?

Tags: r, postgis

I'm trying to execute the following code in R

```
system('"C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin/raster2pgsql" -s 32630 -a -f raster Y:/Sen2R_Download/prueba_sergio/raster3/SCL/S2B2A_20180731_137_sen2r_SCL_10.tif sentinel > Y:/Sen2R_Download/prueba_sergio/rastersql27.sql')
```

But it throws an error

```
ERROR: Unable to read raster file: sentinel
```

But this error shouldn't happen and when I execute the same in cmd it works well

```
C:\Users\Public\Documents>"C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin/raster2pgsql" -s 32630 -a -f raster Y:/Sen2R_Download/prueba_sergio/raster3/SCL/S2B2A_20180731_137_sen2r_SCL_10.tif sentinel > Y:/Sen2R_Download/prueba_sergio/rastersql27.sql
Processing 1/1: Y:/Sen2R_Download/prueba_sergio/raster3/SCL/S2B2A_20180731_137_sen2r_SCL_10.tif
```

What can I do to make it work with R?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the same command with `system2` instead.

See https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.html for more details. Specifically the section regarding differences between Unix and windows